# How to use HextoBin in Delphi Firemonkey for Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, indy

I'm trying to adopt some Windows code to Android, but I am unsuccessful.

When I try to compile the following code, I get an error:

> [DCC Error] There is no overloaded version of 'HexToBin' that can be called with these arguments

```
var
  BinaryStream: TMemoryStream;
  HexStr: String;
  WSocket: TWSocket;
begin
  HexStr := memo1.Text;
  BinaryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    BinaryStream.Size := Length(HexStr) div 2;
    if BinaryStream.Size > 0 then
    begin
      HexToBin(PChar(HexStr), BinaryStream.Memory, BinaryStream.Size);
      HexStr:='';
      HexStr:=MemoryStreamToString(BinaryStream);
      memo1.Text:=HexStr;
      IdUDPClient1.Send(HexStr);
```

Comment: Why are you showing all the other code. Can't we just focus on the one line that doesn't compile?

Comment: For a better understanding of what is happening in my code. Because I'm not sure that all properly coded.

Comment: @David Heffernan Sorry if something is not done properly, I'm new and don't quite understand how to correctly execute all

Answer (score 2):

For Android you have to use one of these overloads:

```
function HexToBin(const Text: PChar; TextOffset: Integer;
  var Buffer: TBytes; BufOffset: Integer; Count: Integer): Integer; overload;

function HexToBin(const Text: TBytes; TextOffset: Integer;
  var Buffer: TBytes; BufOffset: Integer; Count: Integer): Integer; overload;
```

You can best achieve this by using a TBytesStream instead of a TMemoryStream.

A valid call could then look like this:

```
var
  BinaryStream: TBytesStream;
  bytes: TBytes;
  HexStr: String;
begin
  HexStr := memo1.Text;
  SetLength(bytes, Length(HexStr) div 2);
  HexToBin(PWideChar(HexStr), 0, bytes, 0, Length(bytes));
  BinaryStream := TBytesStream.Create(bytes);
  ...
```

Comment: Can you please give some sample, can't get to work (( same error

var
  BinaryStream: TBytesStream;
  HexaStr:string;
  Begin
  BinaryStream := TBytesStream.Create;
    try
    BinaryStream.Size := Length(HexaStr) div 2;
    if BinaryStream.Size > 0 then
HexToBin(Pwidechar(HexaStr),0, BinaryStream.Memory, 0,BinaryStream.Size);

Comment: This doesn't work too((
var
  LStr1, LStr2: WideString;
 
begin
  { Store the text in the memo to a String variable. }
  LStr1 := Memo2.Lines.Text;
  { Set the length of the String to hold the conversion. }
  SetLength(LStr2, Length(LStr1) div 4);
  { Call the hexadecimal to binary conversion procedure. }
  HexToBin(PWideChar(LStr1), LStr2[1], Length(LStr1) div SizeOf(Char));
  { Output the results to Memo1. }
  Memo1.Lines.Text := LStr2;

Comment: @AKYLA, I have added an example for the call.