# Delphi Tokyo HexToBin for Linux

Tags: linux, delphi

I have a procedure in Delphi Berlin which I want to convert for Linux as a console application. Below is my procedure:

```
StrVal is declare as Private

procedure DoGetSy();
var
  s: String;
  n: Integer;
  HasSy: Boolean;
begin
  HasSy := False;
  if ch = '_' then begin
    SyBegPos := ix-1;
    sy := StrCharSetSy;
    GetChar();
    GetIdent();
    Ident := '_' + Ident;
    HasSy := True;
  end;
  if (not HasSy) and (IBServerOptions.SQLServerVersion in [st_Firebird_25, st_Firebird_30]) then begin
    if (ch = '0') and ((CurCh()='x') or (CurCh()='X')) then begin
      // hex literal (integer)
      sy := IntValSy;
      GetChar();
      GetChar();
      StrVal := '';
      while CharInSet(ch, ['0'..'9','A'..'F','a'..'f']) do begin
        StrVal := StrVal + ch;
        GetChar();
      end;
//    (?) Int64
//      IntVal := StrToInt('$' + StrVal);
      IntVal := 0;
      if TryStrToInt(StrVal, n) then begin
        IntVal := n;
      end;
      HasSy := True;
    end
    else if ((UpCase(ch) = 'X') and (CurCh() = '''')) then begin
      // hex literal (binary string)
      GetChar();
      sy := StrValSy;
      StrQuoteCh := ch;
      StrVal := GetStr();
      n := Length(StrVal);
      if (Odd(n)) then n := (n div 2) + 1
      else n := n div 2;
      StrVal := LowerCase(StrVal);
      SetLength(s, n);
      HexToBin(PChar(StrVal), PChar(s), n);// in Linux here compiler gives exception as There is no overloaded version of 'HexToBin' that can be called with these arguments
      StrVal := s;
      HasSy := True;
    end;
  end; // Firebird 2.5, 3.0
  if not HasSy then begin
    inherited;
    if (sy = StrValSy) and (StrQuoteCh = '"') and
       (IBServerOptions.SQLDialect = 3) and (StrVal <> '') then begin
      sy := IdentSy;
      Ident := StrVal;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

in Linux it's using following method:

```
procedure BinToHex(const Buffer: TBytes; BufOffset: Integer;
  var Text: TBytes; TextOffset: Integer; Count: Integer); overload;
```

where as in Windows it work perfectly. How can I overcome with this?

Comment: If you look at the source (System.Classes), you'll see that the BinToHex and HexToBin functions are only available `$IFNDEF NEXTGEN`, and I'm pretty sure (although I could be wrong - I've not looked at the Linux support much because I don't need it currently) that the Linux compiler is NEXTGEN, so those functions would not be available. The Windows compiler is not NEXTGEN, so the functions would be available there.

Comment: Yes, the Linux compiler is a NEXTGEN compiler

Comment: Related: [How to use HextoBin in Delphi Firemonkey for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962063/).

Answer (score 2):

The overloaded version of `HexToBin()` that you are trying to call simply does not exist on the NEXTGEN compilers (iOS, Android, and Linux).  These are the only overloads available on those compilers:

```
function HexToBin(const Text: PChar; TextOffset: Integer;
  var Buffer: TBytes; BufOffset: Integer; Count: Integer): Integer; overload;

function HexToBin(const Text: TBytes; TextOffset: Integer;
  var Buffer: TBytes; BufOffset: Integer; Count: Integer): Integer; overload;
```

You will have to adjust your code accordingly.